# Real-time Debug Android Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, отладка, adb

ADb настроил, как сделать, что бы при запуске игры в редакторе, она сразу же открывала ее в телефоне, тоесть нажал Play а юнити, и игра запустилась через отладку на телефоне и действия повторялись:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- На телефоне в настройках Developer Options (если открыть под рутом) находим опцию Debugging - Android debugging
- Скачиваешь на телефоне *UnityRemote 5* (через google play) и устанавливаешь её
- На ПК устанавливаешь Android SDK и JDK. Второе вроде не обязательно, но на всякий случай надо
- В *Unity* в `Edit` → `Preferences` → `External Tools` прописываешь путь к Android SDK и JDK
- В *Unity* в `Edit` → `Project Settings` → `Editor` устанавливаешь `Unity Remote` в значение `Any Android Device`.
- В *Unity* в пункте `File` → `Build Settings` — добавляешь свою сцену и переключаешь платформу на Android.
- Теперь подсоединяешь телефон к ПК, на телефоне запускаешь *UnityRemote* и пока он запущен в *Unity* нажимаешь `Play`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня VR проект, при переключении Any Android Device, движение в 360 градусов просто напросто не работает, ни в редакторе ни в телефоне, то есть акселерометр никак не пашет

Comment: Попробуй для начала простой код написать и подключить отладку. Если всё работает, то скорее всего проблема в коде и надо смотреть именно его

Comment: Решил проблему из этой темы, спасибо за наводку. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/985989/google-cardboard-not-move-the-camera-when-im-using.html

Comment: @KostyaLikhachev кстати, можешь создать еще вопрос с упором именно на то, что при VR и Cardboard SDK отладка не получается и ответить сразу же на свой вопрос переводом ответа из той ссылки (указав на источник). Чтоб было всем полезно